# Redshift CREATE TABLE AS taking a long time from simple query

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

When I run a certain query by itself, it is returning in LESS than 1 second.  When I try to create a table from that query using CREATE TABLE (name) AS, it is running up to 15 minutes with no completion.

I've made lots of tables as queries and not had this problem.  Should it take that much longer to make a table out of a query that on its own takes under one second to return?

Comment: depends - if you are using an ide it may be adding a limit statement?

Comment: I'm using the web query tool on AWS Redshift console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case i highly doubt that some other user in the database is hitting the cluster with some performance taxing queries so it's allocating a lot of it to that query & so it has a hard time performing other ones like your creation.

---

For reference, here are the elements that could be slowing your query (source link below):

- **Number of nodes, processors, or slices** : compute node is partitioned into slices. More nodes means more processors and more slices, which enables your queries to process faster.
- **Node types** – An Amazon Redshift cluster can use either dense storage or dense compute nodes. The dense storage node types are recommended for substantial data storage needs, while dense compute node types are optimized for performance-intensive workloads. Each node type offers different sizes and limits to help you scale your cluster appropriately. The node size determines the storage capacity, memory, CPU, and price of each node in the cluster.
- **Data distribution** – Amazon Redshift stores table data on the compute nodes according to a table's distribution style. When you execute a query, the query optimizer redistributes the data to the compute nodes as needed to perform any joins and aggregations. Choosing the right distribution style for a table helps minimize the impact of the redistribution step by locating the data where it needs to be before the joins are performed.
- **Data sort order** – Amazon Redshift stores table data on disk in sorted order according to a table’s sort keys. The query optimizer and the query processor use the information about where the data is located to reduce the number of blocks that need to be scanned and thereby improve query speed. For more information, see Choosing Sort Keys.
- **Dataset size** – A higher volume of data in the cluster can slow query performance for queries, because more rows need to be scanned and redistributed. You can mitigate this effect by regular vacuuming and archiving of data, and by using a predicate to restrict the query dataset.
- **Concurrent operations(Most Frequent)** – Running multiple operations at once can affect query performance. Each operation takes one or more slots in an available query queue and uses the memory associated with those slots. If other operations are running, enough query queue slots might not be available. In this case, the query has to wait for slots to open before it can begin processing. For more information about creating and configuring query queues, see Implementing Workload Management.
- **Query structure** – How your query is written affects its performance. As much as possible, write queries to process and return as little data as meets your needs. For more information, see Amazon Redshift Best Practices for Designing Queries.
- **Code compilation** – Amazon Redshift generates and compiles code for each query execution plan.
  The compiled code executes faster because it eliminates the overhead of using an interpreter. You generally have some overhead cost the first time code is generated and compiled. As a result, the performance of a query the first time you run it can be misleading. The overhead cost might be especially noticeable when you run one-off queries. Run a query a second time to determine its typical performance.
  Similarly, be careful about comparing the performance of the same query sent from different clients. The execution engine generates different code for the JDBC connection protocols and ODBC and psql (libpq) connection protocols. If two clients use different protocols, each client incurs the first-time cost of generating compiled code, even for the same query. Other clients that use the same protocol, however, benefit from sharing the cached code. A client that uses ODBC and a client running psql with libpq can share the same compiled code.
  The compiled code segments are stored locally on the cluster and remotely in an AWS account level cache. Subsequent executions of the same query can run faster because it can skip the compilation phase. The cache persists after cluster reboots, but is wiped by maintenance upgrades.
  When there is a local cache miss, the remote shared cache is used. If there is a remote cache hit, the cached item is fetched to the local cache. The remote cache is shared across clusters within the same AWS account. Thus, the query can run faster:

  - When the query is run on different clusters of the same account.
  - When the query is run in different sessions across a cluster.
  - And often, when the query has different query parameters but the same execution plan.

---

[**Factors Affecting Query Performance**]
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-query-performance.html

Comment: Thank You! I think too what was confusing me was using the AWS web based query editor. Using the stand alone desktop Java tool along with the cluster info on the web page is a little more sensical.